# Flutter Autocomplete Showing Irrelevant Tags in starting in VS Code Editor

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

There are some irrelevant suggestions are coming up in flutter dart code on VS Code like below image.
Instead it should show the related functions or arguments/parameters first.
I am using Windows 10 Pro, any suggestions to fix the issue?
I have tried uninstalling all extensions and reinstalling, disabled/enabled visual studio light theme etc. as well but nothing worked.

[image: Irrelevant suggestions are coming up in flutter dart code on VS Code.]

Comment: You can try with upgrading `v2.8`

Comment: when did it started?

Comment: Anything related to VS Code comes from the Flutter/Dart Code extensions. You should file an issue at the extension's [repository](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues) if what you see is reproducible and valid.

Comment: It is coming since starting when I started using flutter? Should I re-install VS code?